# ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed throws exception

Tags: vsto, clickonce

In the code inside my ClickOnce-deployed application, `ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed` throws an exception saying "Access to the path 'Deployment' is denied."

The VSTO file for this app includes:

```
<deployment install="false" mapFileExtensions="true" />
```

Any suggestions about what the "Deployment" path is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Process Monitor, I was able to isolate the issue.

It turns out that the user running the application requires Write access to the folder:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Deployment
```

That folder did not exist.

Once I created it, and granted the user Modify access to it, the code worked.

Comment: How did you employ Process Monitor?  Thanks.

Comment: @Sabuncu - You can download and install it from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx